# When i try to use thread to rename my file name and close and flush the FileStream , it will give me error Cannot access a closed file

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have large amount of data, i need to make  '.txt' file in every 5 sec and write next coming data in that newly created '.txt' file but when i try to use Timer thread for that for sometime program run properly but after sometime it will through exception cannot access a closed file . Please help me in my code and suggest me what has to be done.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Service s = new Service();
            s.init();
        }
    }


    class Service
    {
        FileStream fs = null;
        int filecount = 0;
        long a = 1000000000000000;
      // int j = 0;

        public void  init()
        {
            initialiseFile(filecount);
            timer();
            WriteINFile();
        }

        private void initialiseFile( int filecount)
        {

                fs = File.Create("C:\\Users\\yogesh.ghonate\\source\\repos\\ConsoleApp3\\ConsoleApp3\\NewFolder1\\Index_" + filecount + ".txt");        
        }
        private void WriteINFile()
        {
            string sen = " write in file ";

                for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
                {
                    Byte[] title = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(sen);

                    fs.Write(title, 0, title.Length);
                }
        }

        public void timer()
        {
            System.Timers.Timer th = new System.Timers.Timer();
            th.Interval = 5000;
            th.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(run);
            th.Start();         
            run(th, null);
        }

        public void run(object state, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Commitzfile();
        }

        private void Commitzfile()
        {

            //Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            //stopwatch.Start();
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
            // fs.Dispose();
            //stopwatch.Stop();
            filecount++;
            initialiseFile(filecount);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, a naive solution would be to remove the timer, but I really don't understand why you've convoluted your code in this manner? What purpose does the timer have, **at all**, other than to make your life difficult?

Comment: Note that after initializing the timer, you're calling the `run` method, which will call `CommitzFile`, which will **close the file**. So by the time the timer will tick, calling `fs.Flush()` on it once more is guaranteed to throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most strait forward solution is to add `lock` to your code. This will prevent any race condition, also will make your code a bit slower since it will block threads while the resource is under use.

You can use it like this:

```
// add new lock object
object lockObject = new object();
FileStream fs = null;
int filecount = 0;
long a = 1000000000000000;

…

private void WriteINFile()
{
    string sen = " write in file ";

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        Byte[] title = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(sen);
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            fs.Write(title, 0, title.Length);
        }
    }
}

…

private void Commitzfile()
{
    lock(lockObject)
    {
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
        filecount++;
        initialiseFile(filecount);
    }
}
```

I suggest you read the following documentation about [lock statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)

---

**Update**

In concurrent programming there are a number of problems that need to consider. One of these is the resource management. Usually the problem is presented with the [Dining philosophers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem). The main issue happens when a resource is tried to be used by multiple processes/threads, but the resource is bound to be used by one at a time. In your case it is the FileStream since one thread is trying to write through it all the time while on the other thread it is close and changed. You can see that in some cases it can happen that one closes the stream while the other still trying to write through it **at the same time**. To overcome this issue you need to make sure that the resource is accessed by only one thread at a time. One tool to do this is the lock statement.

Other things to keep in mind:

- Deadlocks.
- How many concurrent thread worth running at the same time.

Hope this brief summary helps. Feel free to ask a new question (or look up if there one already) if you need more info.

Comment: Thanks Buddy , it works Fine , Need one more favour from your side , i haven't work on threading , can you please brief me why and where we use lock.

Comment: @yogesh I am glad that this solved your issue. I have added some brief update.